# Creating a generalized linear model on percent/proportion data that is non-normal, heteroscedastic, and arguably zero-inflated

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, beta-distribution, percentage

My objective here is to evaluate how pre-germination treatments (`Pre.G`)
and light treatments (`Light`) affect percent germination (`PG`)of seeds belonging to three functional groups (`FG`) while also testing for interactions between the independent variables.

My dataframe `GermT` consists of four columns:

'data.frame':   189 obs. of  4 variables:

$ `FG` : Factor w/ 3 levels "ES", "MS", "LS".

$ `Pre.G` : Factor w/ 3 levels "Control", "Abrasion", "Hot Water".

$ `Light` : Factor w/ 3 levels "0", "60", "100".

$ `PG` : Numerical  0 0 3.33 66.67 60 ...

A basic linear model would read as:

```r
lmPG <- lm(PG ~ FG * Pre.G * Light, data = GermT)
```

However, the data is not normal (Shapiro.Test: W = 0.859, p = 2.938e-12) and QQplot appear heteroscedastic (Breusch-Pagan Test: = 34.385, p = 0.0598). A common approach here is to use proportions instead of percentages on a glm with a binomial family and logit link:

```r
glm(GermT$PG/100 ~ FG * Pre.G * Light, data = GermT, 
    family=binomial(link=logit))
```

This improves the QQplot some, but when I plot the effect size using the function `allEffects` from the package `effects` I find that the error margin bar for `Pre.G = Control` in the MS functional group is **very** unusual. For that combination of variables, the mean and confidence interval, as calculated using `summarySE` from the package `Rmisc` is: 0.185 and 0.390 respectively. This is because most of the values here are actually zeroes.

[image: plot(allEffects(glm(GermT$PG/100 ~ FG * Pre.G, data = GermT, family=binomial(link=logit))))]

In fact, the allEffects version of the original linear model appears to illustrate the nature of the data more accurately:

[image: plot(allEffects(lm(PG ~ FG * Pre.G, data = GermT)))]

Note that these `allEffects` plot are built without the Light variable so as to simplify the illustration and because no model has suggested an effect or interaction with Light.

I thought perhaps I would try a zero-inflated beta-distribution model. For this I had to change some values as this model does not accept "1"s.

`GermT$PG2 <- GermT$PG/100`

`GermT$PG2[GermT$PG2 == 1.0000] <- 0.9999`

`gamlss(PG2 ~ FG * Pre.G * Light,  family = BEZI, data = GermT, trace = F)`

However, I am having trouble interpreting this model as using the `summary` or `Anova` functions provide output from every possible variable combination and I require p-values that simply test for variable interaction (what you usually get from using `Anova` on glms). I also cannot run `allEffects` on gamlss, nor can I use `anova` to test how this model differs from one without the interactions.

In short, I have followed the advice I found online on how to deal with this type of data, but so far only the basic linear model works well enough and provides results that are congruent with descriptive statistics and illustrations.

Can you advice on which other approaches I should take? I have tried the arcsine approach but according to Warton & Hui (2011) that approach is "[asinine](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/10-0340.1)". Or perhaps can you advice on how to interpret my beta-distribution zero-inflated model and how to determine if it is the right choice (AIC approach?)?

Or perhaps, is the solution the simplest one of the bunch: the linear model despite its issues?

Comment: Can you share the data at all?

Comment: Just using the proportions of success as the outcome variable in the `glm` is a potential problem, as the variance estimates and proper case weighting depends on the total number of observations. What happens if you analyze data with the response variable as the 2-column matrix of (successes, failures)--see the help page for `family`--or include a `weights` argument in the call to `glm` with the proportions as the outcome variable?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details about what each "observation" consists of: how many seeds were typically examined for each "observation," and whether this was a pre-designed or an observational study. For example, there seem to be no `LS`/`Abrasion` cases. How many `MS`/`Control` cases were there? With all interactions among three 3-level factors you have a very large number of coefficients to estimate, so overfitting could be a risk depending on the actual scale of your study.